# How to code try/except in one place but for many evaluations

Tags: python, numpy

I have a snippet of code like this, with try except wrapped into a function tryprint(), so I can call upon this function multiple times instead of keep writing try except for a dozen of evaluations.

```
import numpy as np
def tryprint(fun):
    try:
        fun
    except ValueError:
        return 'ValueError'

tryprint(np.dot([1,1],[2]))
```

Here because the input is wrong by intention, I expected calling tryprint() on an evaluation would print just 'ValueError' however it resulted in the error msg I tried to avoid:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-a1b49d56a970> in <module>()
      4     except ValueError:
      5         return 'ValueError'
----> 6 tryprint(np.dot([1,1],[2]))
```

What do I need to do to make this function only print 'ValueError' if input is wrong, instead of printing full error msg and stop the cell from running? Thanks.

Comment: The exception occurs outside of the `try/except` block

Comment: Try passing a lambda: `tryprint(lambda: np.dot([1,1],[2]))` Then inside the `try` call `fun` as `fun()`.

Comment: @codespeed worked very well. thanks

Comment: I like coldspeed way, but `with contextlib.suppress` another way to go

Comment: @StephenRauch what do you mean by that? I'm trying to understand where went wrong

Comment: @coldspeed just trying to understand, why do we need lambda here? thanks

Comment: Your errored code was evaluated outside of the try block.  The lambda method means the code is not evaluated until later (inside the try block)

Comment: The only thing that can practically occur within the `try` block is a `NameError` and since your function requires that `fun` is passed to it - no exception can really occur... unless you do something really funny with a custom class to make it do so...  what is it you're actually trying to achieve here?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to pass the function and its args separately:

```
import numpy as np
def tryprint(fun, *args):
    try:
        retVal = fun(*args)
    except ValueError:
        return 'ValueError'
    return retVal

print(tryprint(np.dot, [1,1],[2]))
```

Comment: Why do people accept an answer without upvoting?  I find that odd.  Anyhow, good answer.